# Non deterministic turing machine vs Turing machine with stay option

Tags: turing-machines, automata

According to book by Peter Linz, the transition function for non deterministic Turing machine is:

> $Q\times \Gamma\rightarrow 2^{Q\times \Gamma\times \{L,R\}}$
>   where,
>
> - $Q$ is a set of states
> - $\Gamma$ is a set of tape alphabet
> - $L$ is a movement of head to left
> - $R$ is a movement of head to right

whereas the [definition given by wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-deterministic_Turing_machine#Definition) is

> $Q\times \Gamma \rightarrow (Q\times \Gamma \times \{L,S,R\})$

Book by Ullman et. al. says above transition function is of "Turing machine with Stay option". Ullman's book does not give any formal definition for non deterministic Turing machine. So which definition is correct? I feel Peter Linz's book gives correct definition. Or both are same?

Comment: With your second definition you obtain a deterministic Turing machine. You would get a non-deterministic TM with $Q \times \Gamma \times Q \times \Gamma \times \{L, S, R\}$ or like in Linz' notation  $2^{Q \times \Gamma \to Q \times \Gamma \times \{L, R\}}$.
It is not hard, however, to simulate a "Turing machine with stay option" on a "Turing machine without stay option" and vice versa.
This would be an easy homework exercise, so I encourage you to write it down :)

Comment: Dont you think first two sentences of your comments contradicts each other? First sentence says $Q×Γ→(Q×Γ×{L,S,R})$ is deterministic. Second sentence says its non deterministic. Peter Linz's book says its (TM with stay option) deterministic. So wikipedia is wrong, correct?

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry the Linz part should be $Q \times \Gamma \to 2^{Q \times \Gamma \times \{L, S, R\}}$. With both you get a non-determinsitic TM.
I cannot find anything wrong with the wikipedia definition. They introduce a non-deterministic transition relation $\delta$ and say it is deterministic if $\delta$ is the graph of a function.

Comment: Do you mean Peter Linz missed $S$ in $Q \times \Gamma \to 2^{Q \times \Gamma \times \{L, \color{red}{S}, R\}}$?

Comment: @anir What's written on Wikipedia is $\delta\subseteq(Q\setminus A\times\Sigma)\times(Q\times\Sigma\times\{L,S,R\})$ **not** what you stated (even ignoring the use of $\Gamma$ instead of $\Sigma$ which presumably you did for consistency). It is saying $\delta$ is a *relation* **not** (necessarily) a *function*.

Comment: @anir, no I think Linz does not use the $S$ on purpose. And this is okay because you can actually simulate $S$ with $L, R$. To show this is a simple exercise.

Comment: @DerekElkins ok I feel I understand it now to some extent. Linz used $\rightarrow$ to emphasize that its a function. Wikipedia used $\times$ and said its relation. Now the doubt remained is whether to have $S$? Its different point whether both transition function and relation leads to NTM. I feel there should be well defined transition function, similar to DFA and NFA which are equivalent in power and can simulate each other but have different well defined transition function.

Comment: @PHPNick I understand both definitions of transition function leads to non deterministic TM and can simulate each other. But I feel we should have one well specified fixed definition for transition function for NTM similar to DFA and NFA which are equal in power and can simulate each other, but have different well specified transition functions.

Comment: What is your question now? Linz defines NTMs without stay option via transition functions that map a state-symbol pair into a set of state-symbol-direction triples. Ullman and Wikipedia define it with stay option via a transition relation. Both definitions are equivalent and "correct".
Since the comment section are not good for extended discussion, we should wrap it up pretty soon. Maybe edit your question to clarify what you are asking for.